# Sharing code between OS X (Objective-C) and iOS (Swift)

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, swift

I have a Mac app written in Objective-C. Now I want to make a iOS version of it, written in Swift.

I followed the MVC model from the beginning.

I want to share the model code on both platforms. Now I ran into a problem that I can't solve. In a Objective-C model class, I use `NSFont`, which doesn't exist on iOS. Using `UIFont` gives me the error that it is unknown. `UIKit` is not available there.

What do I need to do that I can use `AppKit` and `UIKit` in one class?

Here I what I did:

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
UIFont* font;
#else 
NSFont* font;
#endif
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go through the WWDC videos. There is one video where Apple engineers explain what they did to have as much of code for Pages and Numbers common between MacOS and iOS. That should give you some ideas.

If you have a huge code base in Objective-C, I don't see any immediate advantage in changing it to Swift.

For the situation where you want a member to be either NSFont or UIFont, your approach doesn't work well at all. Much easier to have somewhere in a header file

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
typedef UIFont MyFont;
#else 
typedef NSFont MyFont;
#endif
```

to avoid having nothing but ifdefs in your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me into the right direction! I already saw the video today and rechecked it. I looked at the Lister sample code as well and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can't. You need to write conditionally compiled code that uses UIKit for iOS and AppKit for Mac OS.

Comment: I think I know what you mean and I did this. I edited my question to show a example. That code gives me the following error: Use of undeclared identifier 'UIFont'

Comment: That's because you need different header files.